# Why doesn't this search term return any results?

Tags: support, search

I searched for `AADSTS50011 analysis` or `AADSTS50011 analysis services` and it doesn't return any results. I would expect for it to return [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302360/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-reply-url) that has these 3 terms in the question

[image]

If I search via Google, it immediately finds it as the first result.
https://www.google.com/search?q=AADSTS50011+analysis+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Do I need to search in a different manner? It seems like I should stick with Google..

Comment: "*It seems like I should stick with Google*" to be honest, that's probably your best bet to search SO. The site search is good if you already know what you look for. Which...means it's sort of self-defeating - in order to find something, you need to know what it is and how to find it.

Comment: Not necessarily google; literally _any_ search engine will do. On-site search is known to be awful, and it's likely never going to be fixed, because SE in general isn't a search engine. None of the features revolve around needing a functional and highly accurate on-site search, so it's simply not prioritised. Unless you need specific features, and by that I mean something you _cannot_ do with a real search engine, use a real search engine instead of on-site search. You'll save yourself a lot of annoyance that way

Comment: One should indeed stick with the tool designed for the job. Search engines such as Google have had so long to evolve to a point where you get *relevant* results rather than hard keyword matches. Stack Overflow's search is as dumb as it can be made to be, relying solely on what information is actually indexed. Good for criteria searches ("give me unanswered questions score > 0"), inadequate for anything else.

Answer (score 7):

I've found that, if you're looking to find a post by searching for specific terms and not a specific phrase, that surrounding each of those terms in quotes is fairly accurate.

For your example, I was able to find the question you were looking for by searching for `"AADSTS50011" "analysis"` ([search result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C76x4.png)). The search string `"AADSTS50011" "analysis" "services"` also works.

Stack Overflow's search functionality can be a bit... Off at times. Google will sometimes yield you better results unless you know exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting.. that is not intuitive at all. `"AADSTS50011" analysis` also works - no quotes around `analysis`. I guess I don't understand why it doesn't work without quotes - what's the reasoning behind that. Is that a bug?

Comment: My guess is that the search string `AADSTS50011 analysis` is trying to find the sentence "AADSTS50011 analysis" (i.e. trying to find those two words next to each other) whereas the search string `"AADSTS50011" analysis` is trying to find the term "AADSTS50011" as well as "analysis" *somewhere within the post*, not necessarily right next to each other, but I'm not 100% sure how it works. Someone more well-versed in dark search magic might be able to explain better than I can!

Comment: @Gabe `AADSTS50011` is part of a code block and I don't think normal search goes through that. Well, unless you use the `code` operator, e.g., [`code:AADSTS50011`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3AAADSTS50011). I don't know why surrounding the term in quotes works. Just a guess: perhaps it enables searching in both code blocks and normal text.

Comment: @VLAZ - Note that searching by the code operator does *not return the question that I linked above (it returns some other question). Also, AADSTS50011 is in the title. Oh well, google it is.

Comment: @Gabe to search in the title, you need the `title` operator, otherwise the search just checks the body, I believe. Using quotes might also change that, I dunno. I know the `code` operator has some other weird rules but not sure why it doesn't work for your question but finds another. The weird rules are about some of the punctuation, I think it might be a skipping it because there is a `:` adjacent to the search term. Again, the on-site search is quite bad at letting you actually find stuff. Unless you know *what* and *how* to find, which is counter to what a search functionality is.